# Java(JavaFX): Maven Proguard doesnt obfuscate FX Ids

Tags: java, maven, javafx, compiler-errors, proguard

I am using the Proguard plugin to obfuscate my project which is using JavaFX.
The problem is, that the Ids in the .fxml files arent obfuscated, so its not possible to connect to the controller.
Already tried on google, without sucess...
Any ideas?
Proguard configuration:

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-final.jar</outjar>
                <includeDependency>true</includeDependency>
                <options>
                    <option>-keep public class com.skriptide.main.Main { public static void
                        main(java.lang.String[]); }
                    </option>
                    <option>-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*,Exceptions</option>
                    <option>-dontusemixedcaseclassnames</option>
                    <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses</option>
                    <option>-verbose</option>
                </options>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jfxswt.jar</lib>
                </libs>
                <assembly>
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
                            <library>true</library>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.fxmisc.richtext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>richtextfx</artifactId>
                            <library>true</library>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                            <library>true</library>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                            <library>true</library>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                            <library>true</library>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </assembly>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.skriptide.main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.1</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to instruct ProGuard also to rename obfuscated classnames in the .fxml files. Assuming that they are already contained in the original jar file, you can try to add the following option to your proguard configuration:

```
<options>
  ...
  <option>-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml</option>
  ...
</options>
```